# Can anyone tell me that what is the use of a static block in a class?

Tags: java

```
public class myclass{ 

    static{ 

        //some statements here 

    } 

    //some variables declared here 
    //some functions defined here 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the 'static' keyword do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-java)

Comment: THAT PARTICULAR QUESTION IS A POOR DUPE. It's only vaguely related. The linked questions in my answers are far more relevant.

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks

Answer (score 12):

It's a `static` initializer. Analogously to the instance initializer ([§8.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6)), you can use it to initialize your `class` when it's loaded. It is *NOT* "invoked" explicitly; it is executed automatically when the `class` is loaded, in textual order (`static` initializer that occurs later in the text is guaranteed to be performed later during the initialization).

You can use a `static` initializer to:

- Initialize some `static` fields
- Perform some other one-time calculations, perhaps something requiring a `try-catch` block, logging events related to the loading of the `class`, making sure that Java's assertion is enabled, etc.

There are some caveats, e.g. a `class` may be reloaded, and usually there are alternatives of writing it (e.g. refactoring into a `private static` named method), but using a `static` initializer is an option.

#### References

- [JLS 8.7 Static initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7)
- [JLS 12.4 Initialization of Classes and Interfaces](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4)

#### Related questions

These questions discuss various aspects of `static` and instance initializers usage:

- [Static initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java)
- [How to handle a static final field initializer that throws checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866770/how-to-handle-a-static-final-field-initializer-that-throws-checked-exception)
- [Why is the order of declarations important for static initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187448/why-is-the-order-of-declarations-important-for-static-initializers)
- [Use of Initializers vs Constructors in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804589/use-of-initializers-vs-constructors-in-java)
- [Are Java static initializers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe)

---

#### An example usage: requiring that assertions are enabled

The following is the prescribed idiom in the [Java Language Guide for Programming With Assertions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) to ensure that assertion is enabled at run-time:

> #### Requiring that Assertions are Enabled
>
> Programmers of certain critical systems might wish to ensure that assertions are not disabled in the field. The following static initialization idiom prevents a class from being initialized if its assertions have been disabled:
>
> ```
> static {
>     boolean assertsEnabled = false;
>     assert assertsEnabled = true; // Intentional side effect!!!
>     if (!assertsEnabled)
>         throw new RuntimeException("Asserts must be enabled!!!");
> }
> ```
>
> Put this `static`-initializer at the top of your class.

By putting this snippet in a `static` initializer for the class, the code will be one of the first thing executed when the class is loaded, before any instances of the class can be created. The code itself checks if Java assertion is enabled, and throws a `RuntimeException` if it's not.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Assertion (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29)

#### Related questions

- [Do you use assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208404/do-you-use-assertions)

Comment: public class StaticTest {

static{
System.out.println("This is the message in static block");
}
public void normalMethod()
{
System.out.println("This is a message from method, After creating the object and invoking this method");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("This is the message in Main, I didnot create the static block");
}
}

Output: 
This is the message in static block
This is the message in Main, I didnot create the static block

Comment: @Vijay: You did write a `static` initializer block for the class, so when it is initialized, the code in the block will be executed.

Answer (score 5):

Static blocks are executed when the class is loaded, so they are a good place to initialize static variables. Especially constants that require more logic than a one-liner may be initialized comfortably using a static block:

```
private static final String MY_CONSTANT;

static{
    // read properties from file
    MY_CONSTANT = properties.get("my.property.name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static blocs are used to initialize static values which might need real code to be initialized.

for example you want to do this

```
static boolean firstBoolean = staticMethodThatGetBoolean();
static boolean secondBoolean = staticMethodThatGetAnotherBoolean();
static int i = //if firstBoolean is true i = 1, if secondBoolean is true i = 2, if firstBoolean and secondBoolean are true i = 3;
```

Either you do something like this :

```
static boolean firstBoolean = staticMethodThatGetBoolean();
static boolean secondBoolean = staticMethodThatGetAnotherBoolean();
static int i = (firstBoolean && secondBoolean)?3:(secondBoolean)?2:(firstBoolean)?1:0;
```

or you create a static bloc to handle all of this.

Another example would be to handle exceptions thrown by staticMethodThatGetBoolean() or staticMethodThatGetAnotherBoolean()

Be careful, static bloc are meant to be initializer blocs in a static context. You must use them to **initialize** your static variables only. Even if you can invoke real code in here, this is a really really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Static loop is executed, when the class is loaded. 
So without creating the object we can execute this loop.

Comment: didn't take long to find the answer to your own question then :)

Comment: Why the downvote?  Answering one's own question is acceptable, there's even a badge for it.  A more complete answer was posted at roughly the same time, but that happens on SO.  The point is to record lots of answers to questions.  Now, the _second_ self-answer should have just been an edit to this one, but this one's fine.

Comment: @David I agree (and didn't downvote) but being able to answer your own question after one minute implies that the OP was too lazy to Google the answer first

Comment: @David: I also didn't downvote, but the answer does say "loop" rather than "function" or "method", which could be confusing.

Comment: @seanizer: There's merit to that point, ya.  I've often been in the middle of answering a quick question only to find that the asker deleted it because he found the answer so quickly elsewhere.  Though, barring excessive duplicates, I would argue in favor of posting good questions on SO even if the answer is already known, simply as a matter of recording the question and answer(s) for people to find later.

Comment: @Douglas: Agreed.  Seems to be simply a language barrier though.  The superfluous comma bothers me even more :)

Comment: no it is only to dominate urself they are giving down vote as i know it i was expecting more better answer wht was my overview so i posted my answer

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Test {
    static int a=3; 
       static int b; 
    static void meth(int x) { 
       System.out.println("x = " + x); 
       System.out.println("a = " + a); 
       System.out.println("b = " + b); 
    } 

    static { 
      System.out.println("Static block initialized."); 
      b = a * 4; System.out.println("a = " + a); 
       System.out.println("b = " + b); 

    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
      meth(42); 
     } 

}
```

output willl be--

```
Static block initialized.
a = 3
b = 12
x = 42
a = 3
b = 12
```

Comment: did you have to provide 2 answers to your own question? How about deleting one?